# $rootScope is not working with me in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the value of my $rootScope inside my function But I wanna get thsi value inside all the functions of my Controller to passe it to another controller:
Can You Help me please

MY HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"   ng-model="u.selected" data-ng-click="consoleClient(u)">
```

my Script Code :

```
$scope.client = {
    id : null,
    nom : '',
    nberPhone : '',
    adresse : '',
    selected : false
};

$scope.consoleClient = function(client) {
    $rootScope.test = client;

    console.log(" lll "+$rootScope.test);
};
console.log(" aaaa "+$rootScope.test);
```

The console log is returning the correct result But the second Out of the function Is returning undefined. Can you explain the reason for me please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because you haven't call to `$scope.consoleClient` so it's not defined outside the function scope. It will work after you call the function:

```
$scope.consoleClient = function(client) {
    $rootScope.test = client;

        console.log(" lll "+$rootScope.test);
};
$scope.consoleClient('clientName');
console.log(" aaaa "+$rootScope.test); // output: ' aaaa clientName'
```

If you want to watch for changes of the variable outside the function, you can do the following:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $rootScope.test;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('Old value: ', oldValue);
    console.log('New value: ', newValue);
}, true); // Note the "true" - Compare the object using "angular.equal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer But I need to get The clientName I passed in parameter How should I get it ?

Comment: The client you're passing in the parameter is a call generated from the view - So it will be available after the user clicked on the checkbox. Note that you should use `ng-change` because it will trigger after the model was changed (Checked/Unchecked)

Comment: Thanks A lot Now I undertand it pretty Well :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I added example for watching changes of the value outside the function scope